# Сравнение времени и даты

Tags: php

Считываю из бд timestamp в таком формате:

```
$date = '2021-10-01T10:53:32.523Z'
if(текущая дата < $date) { // если дата из бд превышает текущей
....
}
else if(текущая дата >= $date && текущая дата <= $date + 2 дня) { // если текущая дата больше либо равна дате из бд и если текущая дата меньше либо равна дате из бд + два дня (тоесть берется диапазон за два дня от текущего момента) 
....
}
```

Как реализовать такие условия?

Comment: дата должна быть датой, а не строкой, чтобы вы могли делать правильное сравнение

Comment: @ArchDemon `$date1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));` я вот так делаю

Comment: и получаете опять строку. А должны получить объект https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.construct.php

Comment: если у вас в БД unix_timestamp то сранивте просто значение с `mktime` , не надо их ни в строки конвертировать ни в datetime